# How to pass a SFC with required props to a slot in vue test utils?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

Following the Vue 3 docs [Slots - Advanced Usage](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/slots.html#Advanced-Usage) you can pass a SFC to a slot to render in your tests which we want to do for some integrated accessibility testing. My SFC has required props that need to be set but I cannot see a way to pass those in as well?

```
import List from '../List.vue';
import ListItem from '../components/ListItem.vue';

const factoryMount = () => mount(List, {
    slots: {
        default: ListItem,
    },
});
```

Gives me this error as the prop is required in ListItem:

```
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "label"
```

Is there a way I can load a SFC to a slot along with its required props?

I've tried using setProps but that can only be used with the mounted component. Is there another way?

Comment: Can you clarify how is the component expected to work? You likely need to provide a wrapper or h() in a slot instead of ListItem that does everything you need, like `default: h(ListItem, { label: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask). This worked:

```
import { h } from 'vue';
import List from '../List.vue';
import ListItem from '../components/ListItem.vue';
        
const factoryMount = () => mount(List, {
    slots: {
        default: h(ListItem, {
            label: 'List item text'
        }),
    },
 });
```